# How to avoid blank lines when logging without Foundation?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a Yesod application with shopping carts which works great. I now want to purge the expired carts in an external app ("app/tasks.hs" in the scaffolding) which will be run with cron. The following code works, but every log message is followed with a blank line. Am I doing something wrong? Side question: how could I convert this to fast-logger? I've read Application.hs in the scaffolding but I didn't manage how to avoid the creation of a foundation...

```
import Control.Monad.Logger                 (runStdoutLoggingT, LoggingT)
import Database.Persist.Sqlite              (runSqlPool)
import Data.Text                            (append)
import Import
import qualified Database.Esqueleto as E

runQueries :: UTCTime -> NominalDiffTime -> SqlPersistT (ResourceT (LoggingT IO)) ()
runQueries now expiration = do
    $(logInfo) "Delete expired shopping carts."
    carts <-
        E.select $
        E.from $ \(c, u) -> do
        E.where_ (     c E.^. CartUpdated E.<. E.val (addUTCTime (- expiration) now)
                 E.&&. c E.^. CartCustomer E.==. u E.^. UserId
                 )
        return (c, u)
    forM_ carts $ \(cart, user) -> do
        cartitems <- selectList [ CartItemCart ==. entityKey cart ] []
        forM_ cartitems $ \ci -> do
            update (cartItemItem $ entityVal ci) [ItemStock +=. (cartItemQuantity $ entityVal ci)]
            delete $ entityKey ci
        delete $ entityKey cart
        $(logInfo) $ "Deleted cart: " `append` (userEmail $ entityVal user)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- Get the settings from all relevant sources
    settings <- loadAppSettingsArgs
        -- fall back to compile-time values, set to [] to require values at runtime
        [configSettingsYmlValue]

        -- allow environment variables to override
        useEnv

    now <- getCurrentTime

    pool <- createPoolConfig (appDatabaseConf settings)

    runStdoutLoggingT $ runResourceT $ runSqlPool (runQueries now $ appCartExpiration settings) pool
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch, that's actually a bug in monad-logger. I've released version 0.3.10.1 that fixes it.

**EDIT** Here's an example of using fast-logger with monad-logger:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Monad.Logger
import System.Log.FastLogger
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    loggerSet <- newStderrLoggerSet defaultBufSize
    let logFunc loc src level str = do
            pushLogStr loggerSet (defaultLogStr loc src level str)
    flip runLoggingT logFunc $ do
        $logInfo "foo"
        $logInfo "foo"
        $logInfo "foo"
        $logInfo "foo"
    flushLogStr loggerSet
```

Comment: Great to know! So (as you didn't make any remark on my code ;-)) I deduce that it isn't too bad. Concerning fast-logger, does it make sense in this context?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't this bug affect Yesod?

Comment: Yesod uses `messageLoggerSource` to format the log messages, so it didn't touch the buggy part of monad-logger. Regarding fast-logger: you can experiment with switching over to see if it gives you a speedup. I would imagine it would, but I can't predict that with certainty.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that you were asking *how* to switch to fast-logger... I'll edit my answer.